# Why does Input.GetMouseButton(0) work for touch devices when the touch count is less than 0, in unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have read the Unity3D documentation related to mouse input and touch input but was not able to find any information that would solve this doubt of mine.
I have also gone through several YouTube videos where they use Input.GetMouseButton() but they too didn't provide any information that would help me with this problem.
Take a look at this snippet, where the else-if executes when I drag on the screen, and not the if statement.

```
public bool isDragging = true;
if(isDragging)
{
  if(Input.touches.Length < 0)
      swipeDelta = Input.GetTouch(0).position - startTouch;
  else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    { 
          swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow BlackThornProd`s video for dragging?

Comment: Because when you drag the `Input.touches.Length` is bigger then `0`! Beside that note that this is extremely inperformant ..  you would rather use `Input.touchCount` so it doesn't allocate an array for the touches every frame ... It should rather be `if(Input.tochCount > 0) ...`

Comment: Thank You @NrdyBhu1 and also derHugo for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:
`getMouseButton` -> true as long as the button is pressed/held.

`getMouseButtonDown` -> true on the Frame the button was pressed.
(talking about `Update()` frames. In FixedUpdate it could be true multiple times depending on fps.)

`TouchPhase.Began` = `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`

`TouchPhase.Ended` = `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`

`Input.touchCount > 0`  or `Input.touchCount == 1` = `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`

So of course, when you hold down 1 Finger, the else-if is executed.

Comment: Thank You, I really appreciate your help, and it finally solved my doubt...!